# Bootstrap Datepicker not working.

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fiddle ex: http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/

So I have been trying to get [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) working and I think I am following the directions but I can't get the calendar to pop up.

TIA

Fiddle example above code below.

```
                 <label class="control-label" for="input08"> 
                    My Start Date
                 </label>
                 <div class="controls">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
                    </script>

                    <div class="input-append date" id="dp3" data-date="12-02-2012" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                        <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" class="datepicker">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript "intention" is correct, you can use style class definition in the jQuery selector, it is absolutely not required to use an ID. 
But your example contains 2 error:
1) the ready function is not "closed" probably you miss "});"  at the end.
2) You habve defined 2 times the "class" attribute on the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look this:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/1/)

You bet initialization the ID of the div that contains everything.
you were aiming at nothing!

```
$('#dp3').datepicker();
```

Comment: D'oh. Thanks sir. Always learning... (sometimes slower than I should)

Comment: No problem! Only those who do nothing never make mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

You had several issues in your code.

- Missing brackets after your ready () call
- Using an id selector instead of an class selector (`#datepicker` refers to `id="datepicker"`, `.datepicker` to `class="datepicker"`)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7VjKN/)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't have an ID set.  And something else that might cause you problems later, is the input has the class attribute defined TWICE, instead list each class in the same attribute seperated by a space:

```
<input id="datepicker" class="span2 datepicker" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/2/

I notice you had some javascript inline trying to reference it by class `$('.datepicker')` which didn't work because you had class attribute defined twice and the second definition is ignored.  The javascript panel used `$('#datepicker')` which didn't work because you didn't have the ID set on the input.  So either jquery selector technique would have worked, you just needed to fix the problems with the element.

Answer (score 0):

Lughino's solution resulted in some strange behavior for me. I think you should remove

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

and

```
$('#dp3').datepicker();
```

And write this code in the javascript box:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dp3').datepicker();
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/111/).

Answer (score 0):

The posted code example contains **2 errors**:

1) The function ready() is not closed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

2) The input element has "class" attribute defined 2 times:
(using the class attribute in the jQuery selector is perfect to find the element(s), no need to use the id)

```
<input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" class="datepicker">
```

should be

```
<input class="span2 datepicker" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012">
```

[jsfiddle with correction](http://jsfiddle.net/EmwFE/480/)